# Microstrategy cube refresh fails when using a different database

Tags: microstrategy

Mstr cube refreshes successfully when using the view from one database only database- 'ETL_owns'.But if I use a view or table in the cube that is created in another database and if I run the cube refresh, the cube gives an error "The user don't have select access"

Can I know how to fix this?
What access needs to be provided to which account?
Not sure which account the micro strategy is using to run a cube refresh too.